# How to add stretch or shrink (plus or minus) to imported graphics?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, microtype

I am using the packages `graphicsx`, `fontspec`, and `microtype`.

I have imported a scalable vector graphics `.svg` image into my document via `\includegraphics[height=\heightof{0123456789}]{myimage.pdf}` where I have converted `myimage.svg` to `myimage.pdf` using Inkscape. I have scaled the image such that its height equals the height of the single digit numbers. I have also used tabular and lining numbers via `Numbers={Lining,Tabular}`. So my imported `.svg` image looks like an in-text symbol that is roughly the same size as a capital letter. This, of course, is good because I can import images that can more or less be used within sentences and paragraphs.

However, I've observed that `microtype`'s `font expansion` feature only stretches/shrinks character glyphs and does not stretch/shrink my character-graphic. I have tried to add stretch or shrink to my character-graphic via the width parameter of the `\includegraphics` command, but it does not allow for the width to be stretched or shrunk (`width=` won't accept a plus in the argument, I haven't had success trying to add a stretch to the width. See below). I haven't found anything in the aforementioned packages that would resolve this issue.

I tried to add stretch/shrink to the character-graphic width via the following method. It fails to stretch/shrink the character-graphic while stretching/shrinking the other text. Note that my MWE doesn't provide the `svg` graphic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif 4}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    Kerning=On,Numbers={Lining,Tabular}
]
\usepackage[%
    protrusion=true%character protrusion, default=true
    ,factor=1000%units: 1/1000 of character width, default=1000
    ,expansion=true%font expansion, default=true
    ,stretch=250%units: thousandths of an em, default=20
]{microtype}%
\newcommand{\myimage}{%
    \begingroup%
    \sbox0{0123456789}%
    %\includegraphics[height={\ht0}]{myimage.pdf}%
    \includegraphics[height={\ht0},width={0.5762\ht0 plus 0.1441\ht0 minus 0.1441\ht0}]{myimage.pdf}%
    \endgroup%0.5762 is the width/height ratio, the 0.1441 stretch and shrink numbers are exaggerated, but they don't work regardless
}
\usepackage[indent=0pt]{parskip}
\begin{document}
The following line is stretched, except for the character-graphic.\\
\myimage{}%
It fails to stretch/shrink the character-graphic while stretch/shrink.\\
The following line is shrunk, except for the character-graphic.:\\
\myimage{}%
It fails to stretch/shrink the character-graphic while stretching/shrinking the other text.
\par
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
For comparison, I've removed font expansion in the following line:\\
\myimage{}%
It fails to stretch/shrink the character-graphic while stretching/shrinking the other text.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: your observation is correct: font expansion only applies to, well, fonts, not to images. Also, the `plus` and `minus` operators can only be used for glue. So I don't think there's anything you can do here.

Comment: Not that it helps you, but adaptive sizes of images are possible in ConTeXt lmtx (since Spring 2022).